# Get ISO 3166-1 country code as a GMSPlace result

Tags: ios, google-places-api

I need to implement a city search dialogue field in my app and use
the ISO 3166-1 country code of the search result.
The country in the result is as a string in the current locale (e.g. "United Kingdom", "Vereinigtes Königreich", ...) instead of just "uk", which is a problem. I could do a string search for all 248 countries in all languages google maps supports but that is very error prone.

Is there a way to include the country code in the search result?

My work around for now is to reverse lookup the reported coordinate afterwards but that's an additional request, resulting in wait time for the user.